# How would be sorting behaviour when sorted by _id when _id is not default ObjectId()?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

In my mongodb collection I have overrided `_id` so `_id` is not instance of [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)
example record is

`db.registrations.findOne()` gives

```
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : 156568417304061, "uid" : 156568728002501}, "tid" : 2 }
```

Here `_id` is not instance of `ObjectId()`
What would be sorting behaviour when I will sort collection by `_id`

```
db.registrations.find().sort({_id: 1}) // This works but dont know what is sorting order
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects:

> When comparing values of different BSON types, MongoDB uses the following comparison order, from lowest to highest:
>
> 1. MinKey (internal type)
> 2. Null
> 3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles, decimals)
> 4. Symbol, String
> 5. **Object**
> 6. Array
> 7. BinData
> 8. ObjectId
> 9. Boolean
> 10. Date
> 11. Timestamp
> 12. Regular Expression
> 13. MaxKey (internal type)

For your case it is Objects https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects:

> MongoDB’s comparison of BSON objects uses the following order:
>
> 1. Recursively compare key-value pairs in the order that they appear within the BSON object.
> 2. Compare the key field names.
> 3. If the key field names are equal, compare the field values.
> 4. If the field values are equal, compare the next key/value pair (return to step 1). An object without further pairs is less than an object with further pairs.

Few examples of ascending sort:

#### Order of keys matters:

```
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : 156568417304061, "uid" : 156568728002501}}, 
{ "_id" : {"uid" : 156568728002501, "mtid" : 156568417304061}},
```

because `"mtid"` is less than `"uid"`

#### When keys are the same, compare values:

```
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : 156568417304061, "uid" : 156568728002501}}, 
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : 156568417304062, "uid" : 156568728002501}},
```

because `156568417304061` is less than `156568417304062`

#### Comparing values type matters:

```
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : 156568417304061, "uid" : 156568728002501}}, 
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : "156568417304060", "uid" : 156568728002501}},
```

because number `156568417304061` is less than string `156568417304060`